# Undirect a Graph

Tags: code-golf, array, graph-theory

## Introduction

In this challenge, you are given a directed graph with self-loops, and your task is to convert it to an undirected graph without self-loops.

## Input

Your input is a directed graph with vertex set `{0, 1, ..., n-1}` for some natural number `n ≥ 0` (or `{1, 2, ..., n}` if you use 1-based indexing).
The graph is given as a length-`n` list `L` where `L[i]` is a list of the out-neighbors of vertex `i`.
For example, the list `[[0,1],[0],[1,0,3],[]]` represents the graph

```
.-.
| v
'-0<--2-->3
  ^   |
  |   |
  v   |
  1<--'
```

Note that the neighbor lists are not necessarily ordered, but they are guaranteed to be duplicate-free.

## Output

Your output is another graph in the same format as the input, obtained from it as follows.

1. Delete all self-loops.
2. For each remaining edge `u -> v`, add the reversed edge `v -> u` if it's not already present.

As with the input, the neighbor lists of the output graph may be unordered, but they cannot contain duplicates.
For the above graph, a correct output would be `[[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,3],[2]]`, which represents the graph

```
0<->2<->3
^   ^
|   |
v   |
1<--'
```

## Rules

You can use 0-based or 1-based indexing in the graphs.
Both functions and full programs are acceptable.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Test Cases

These test cases use 0-based indexing; increment each number in the 1-based case.
These neighbor lists are sorted in ascending order, but it is not required.

```
[] -> []
[[0]] -> [[]]
[[],[0,1]] -> [[1],[0]]
[[0,1],[]] -> [[1],[0]]
[[0,1],[0],[1,0,3],[]] -> [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,3],[2]]
[[3],[],[5],[3],[1,3],[4]] -> [[3],[4],[5],[0,4],[1,3,5],[2,4]]
[[0,1],[6],[],[3],[3],[1],[4,2]] -> [[1],[0,5,6],[6],[4],[3,6],[1],[1,2,4]]
[[6],[0,5,1],[5,4],[3,5],[4],[5,6],[0,3]] -> [[1,6],[0,5],[4,5],[5,6],[2],[1,2,3,6],[0,3,5]]
[[1,0],[5,1],[5],[1],[5,7],[7,1],[],[1]] -> [[1],[0,3,5,7],[5],[1],[5,7],[1,2,4,7],[],[1,4,5]]
[[2,8,0,9],[5,2,3,4],[0,2],[3,7,4],[8,1,2],[5,1,9,2],[6,9],[6,5,2,9,0],[9,1,2,0],[3,9]] -> [[2,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,8],[0,1,4,5,7,8],[1,4,7,9],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,7,9],[7,9],[0,2,3,5,6,9],[0,1,2,4,9],[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
.e-.|f}k@QTUQbkQ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e-.%7Cf%7Dk%40QTUQbkQ&input=%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C3%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D&debug=0) or [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FQ.Qp%22+-%3E+%22Q.e-.%7Cf%7Dk%40QTUQbkQ&input=%22Test+Cases%3A%22%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B0%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C3%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B3%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B1%2C3%5D%2C%5B4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B6%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B4%2C2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B6%5D%2C%5B0%2C5%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%2C4%5D%2C%5B3%2C5%5D%2C%5B4%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B5%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B5%2C7%5D%2C%5B7%2C1%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B2%2C8%2C0%2C9%5D%2C%5B5%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B0%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C7%2C4%5D%2C%5B8%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C1%2C9%2C2%5D%2C%5B6%2C9%5D%2C%5B6%2C5%2C2%2C9%2C0%5D%2C%5B9%2C1%2C2%2C0%5D%2C%5B3%2C9%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                   implicit: Q = input
.e             Q   enumerated mapping of Q (k index, b out-neighbors):
     f     UQ         filter [0, 1, ..., len(Q)-1] for elements T, which satisfy:
      }k@QT              k in Q[T]
                      # this are the in-neighbors
   .|        b        setwise union with b 
  -           k       remove k
```

Comment: By the way, `.e` was just switched from `k,Y` to `k,b`, so to run this, use `.e-.|f}k@QTUQbkQ`

Comment: @isaacg Will do so, once the online compiler updates.

Comment: It has been updated.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, <s>43</s> <s>40</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

*2 bytes saved by Sp3000.*

This started out as a really elegant solution and then grew increasingly hideous as I tried patching up some holes I overlooked. I'm not sure yet if the original idea is still salvageable, but I'll try my best...

```
q~_,,\ff{&W+0=)}_z..-{_,{;(},+}%`
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%2C%2C%5Cff%7B%26W%2B0%3D)%7D_z..-%7Bee%7B1%3D%7D%2C0f%3D%7D%25%60&input=%5B%5B1%200%5D%20%5B5%201%5D%20%5B5%5D%20%5B1%5D%20%5B5%207%5D%20%5B7%201%5D%20%5B%5D%20%5B1%5D%5D) Alternatively, [run the entire test harness](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%22-%3E%22%2F0%3D'%2CSer%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~_%2C%2C%5Cff%7B%26W%2B0%3D)%7D_z..-%7Bee%7B1%3D%7D%2C0f%3D%7D%25%60%0A%0AoNo%7D%2F&input=%5B%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B0%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%5B0%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%5B0%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C3%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B0%2C2%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B3%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B1%2C3%5D%2C%5B4%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B3%5D%2C%5B4%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B0%2C4%5D%2C%5B1%2C3%2C5%5D%2C%5B2%2C4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C1%5D%2C%5B6%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B4%2C2%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%5B0%2C5%2C6%5D%2C%5B6%5D%2C%5B4%5D%2C%5B3%2C6%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B6%5D%2C%5B0%2C5%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%2C4%5D%2C%5B3%2C5%5D%2C%5B4%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%2C6%5D%2C%5B0%2C5%5D%2C%5B4%2C5%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B2%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C6%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%2C5%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B5%2C1%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B5%2C7%5D%2C%5B7%2C1%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B1%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%2C5%2C7%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B5%2C7%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C7%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C4%2C5%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B2%2C8%2C0%2C9%5D%2C%5B5%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B0%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C7%2C4%5D%2C%5B8%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C1%2C9%2C2%5D%2C%5B6%2C9%5D%2C%5B6%2C5%2C2%2C9%2C0%5D%2C%5B9%2C1%2C2%2C0%5D%2C%5B3%2C9%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5B2%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C8%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C4%2C5%2C7%2C8%5D%2C%5B1%2C4%2C7%2C9%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C8%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C7%2C9%5D%2C%5B7%2C9%5D%2C%5B0%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C9%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C9%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%5D).

I'll add an explanation once I'm sure the patient is dead.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 107 bytes

Still trying to figure out if I can golf this more, but for now, this is the best I can do.

```
def u(g):e=enumerate;o=[set(_)-{i}for i,_ in e(g)];[o[j].add(i)for i,_ in e(o)for j in _];print map(list,o)
```

I use sets to prevent duplicates; also, unlike `list.remove(i)`, `{S}-{i}` doesn't throw an error if `i` is not in `S`.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 78 bytes

Finally some use for ruby's set operators (`[1,2]&[2]==[2]` and `[3,4,5]-[4]==[3,5]`).

```
->k{n=k.size;n.times{|i|n.times{|j|(k[j]&[i])[0]&&k[i]=(k[i]<<j).uniq-[i]}};k}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/a1DsTd), including all test cases, which it passes.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
l~_,,:T.-_T\ff&Tf.e&.|:e_p
```

Not very short...

#### Explanation

```
l~                           e# Read the input.
  _,,:T                      e# Get the graph size and store in T.
       .-                    e# Remove self-loops from the original input.
         _T\ff&              e# Check if each vertex is in each list, and
                             e# return truthy if yes, or empty list if no.
               Tf.e&         e# Convert truthy to vertex numbers.
                    .|       e# Merge with the original graph.
                      :e_    e# Remove empty lists.
                         p   e# Format and print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript(ES6), 96 <s>110</s>

Creating adjacency sets from adjacency list, that helps avoiding duplicates.
Ad last it rebuilds the lists starting from the sets.

```js
//Golfed 
U=l=>
  l.map((m,n)=>m.map(a=>a-n?s[n][a]=s[a][n]=1:0),s=l.map(m=>[]))
  &&s.map(a=>[~~k for(k in a)])

// Ungolfed

undirect=(adList)=>(
  adSets=adList.map(_ => []),
  adList.forEach((curAdList,curNode)=>{
    curAdList.forEach(adNode=>{
      if (adNode!=curNode) {
        adSets[curNode][adNode]=1,
        adSets[adNode][curNode]=1
      }
    })  
  }),
  adSets.map(adSet=>[~~k for(k in adSet)])
)

// Test
out=s=>OUT.innerHTML+=s+'\n'

test=[
 [ [], [] ]
,[ [[0]], [[]] ]
,[ [[],[0,1]] , [[1],[0]] ]
,[ [[0,1],[]] , [[1],[0]] ]

,[ [[0,1],[0],[1,0,3],[]] , [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,3],[2]] ]
,[ [[3],[],[5],[3],[1,3],[4]] , [[3],[4],[5],[0,4],[1,3,5],[2,4]] ]
,[ [[0,1],[6],[],[3],[3],[1],[4,2]] , [[1],[0,5,6],[6],[4],[3,6],[1],[1,2,4]] ] 
,[ 
   [[6],[0,5,1],[5,4],[3,5],[4],[5,6],[0,3]] ,
   [[1,6],[0,5],[4,5],[5,6],[2],[1,2,3,6],[0,3,5]]  
 ]
,[
  [[1,0],[5,1],[5],[1],[5,7],[7,1],[],[1]] , 
  [[1],[0,3,5,7],[5],[1],[5,7],[1,2,4,7],[],[1,4,5]]
 ]

,[
  [[2,8,0,9],[5,2,3,4],[0,2],[3,7,4],[8,1,2],[5,1,9,2],[6,9],[6,5,2,9,0],[9,1,2,0],[3,9]] ,
  [[2,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,8],[0,1,4,5,7,8],[1,4,7,9],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,7,9],[7,9],[0,2,3,5,6,9],  [0,1,2,4,9],[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
 ]
] 

show=l=>'['+l.map(a=>'['+a+']').join(',')+']'

test.forEach(t => (
  r = U(t[0]),
  ck = show(r) == show(t[1]),           
  out('Test ' + (ck ? 'OK: ':'FAIL: ') + show(t[0])+' -> ' + 
      '\nResult: ' + show(r) + 
      '\nCheck : ' + show(t[1]) + '\n\n')
) )
```

```html
<pre id=OUT></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 150

```
a->{int i=0,j,k=a.size();for(;i<k;a.get(i).remove((Object)i++))for(j=k;j-->0;)if(a.get(j).contains(i)&!a.get(i).contains(j))a.get(i).add(j);return a;}
```

Expanded, runnable code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function
public class C {
    static Function<List<List<Integer>>, List<List<Integer>>> f = a -> {
        int i = 0, j, k = a.size();
        for (; i < k; a.get(i).remove((Object) i++)) {
            for (j = k; j-- > 0;) {
                if (a.get(j).contains(i) & !a.get(i).contains(j)) {
                    a.get(i).add(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f.apply(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
                new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(0, 1)),
                new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1)),
                new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 3)),
                new ArrayList(Arrays.asList()))
        )));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>84</s> <s>66</s> 64 bytes

Using 1-based indexing.

```
MapIndexed[Union[#,First/@l~Position~Tr@#2]~Complement~#2&,l=#]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy - 87

```
u={g->g.eachWithIndex{n,i->g[i]=n-i;g[i].each{g[it]<<i}};g.each{it=it.sort().unique()}}
```

Full script to run tests:

```
u={g->g.eachWithIndex{n,i->g[i]=n-i;g[i].each{g[it]<<i}};g.each{it=it.sort().unique()}}
assert u([]) == []
assert u([[0]]) == [[]]
assert u([[],[0,1]]) == [[1],[0]]
assert u([[0,1],[]]) == [[1],[0]]
assert u([[0,1],[0],[1,0,3],[]]) == [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,3],[2]]
assert u([[3],[],[5],[3],[1,3],[4]]) == [[3],[4],[5],[0,4],[1,3,5],[2,4]]
assert u([[0,1],[6],[],[3],[3],[1],[4,2]]) == [[1],[0,5,6],[6],[4],[3,6],[1],[1,2,4]]
assert u([[6],[0,5,1],[5,4],[3,5],[4],[5,6],[0,3]]) == [[1,6],[0,5],[4,5],[5,6],[2],[1,2,3,6],[0,3,5]]
assert u([[1,0],[5,1],[5],[1],[5,7],[7,1],[],[1]]) == [[1],[0,3,5,7],[5],[1],[5,7],[1,2,4,7],[],[1,4,5]]
assert u([[2,8,0,9],[5,2,3,4],[0,2],[3,7,4],[8,1,2],[5,1,9,2],[6,9],[6,5,2,9,0],[9,1,2,0],[3,9]]) == [[2,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,8],[0,1,4,5,7,8],[1,4,7,9],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,7,9],[7,9],[0,2,3,5,6,9],[0,1,2,4,9],[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 127 bytes

```
l=list;g=l(map(set,eval(input())))
for i in range(len(g)):
    for j in g[i]:g[j]=g[j]^g[j]&{j}|{i}
print(l(map(l,g)))
```

[Try online](http://repl.it/oH4)

Not my best attempt...